# What are the values stored in requests.seen file in Scrapy?

Tags: python, django, web-crawler, scrapy

Some sample values in my requests.seen file are

f4e2f84g6g987t69896gg83552ccb8c36bdff296

ccb8c36bdff29651d3080c9644b117364de75cd7

9ec11d5f1a4cda70af990ad40843615a5f1a4cda

I know they are some representation of the URLS I've crawled. How do I convert these values to URLS? Or better still, how do I convert a URL into an equivalent representation and check if it's there in the requests.seen file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see request fingerprint function
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/request.py

> The request fingerprint is a hash that uniquely identifies the resource the
>       request points to

usage example by [redis dupefilter](https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-redis/blob/master/scrapy_redis/dupefilter.py):

```
def request_seen(self, request):
    fp = request_fingerprint(request)
    added = self.server.sadd(self.key, fp)
    return not added
```